# Conway's Game of life: openMP optimization

Tags: optimization, openmp, schedule, conways-game-of-life, false-sharing

I am trying to optimize my openMP code for Conway's Game of life.
My main problem is related, probably, to *false sharing*.
Here's my code:
This is a method in my class "mondo". m is my scheme, r the number of rows, c number of columns and I am using a toroidal scheme.

```
void evolution() {
    mondo tmp(r, c);
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for(int i=0; i<r; i++) {  
        unsigned a=(i+1)%r, b=(i-1+r)%r;        
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++)  {                                 
            unsigned d=(j+1)%c, e=(j-1+c)%c;     
            int v=(m[a][j]+m[b][j]+m[a][d]+m[b][d]+m[a][e]+m[b][e]+m[i][d]+m[i][e]);             
            if(m[i][j]==1) {              
                if(v<2 || v>3)
                   tmp.m[i][j]=0;
                else  
                    tmp.m[i][j]=1;              
            } 
            else {
                if(v==3)
                   tmp.m[i][j]=1;
                else
                   tmp.m[i][j]=0;
            }                          
        }
    }    
    (*this)=tmp;
}
```

Comment: You might want to revise your indents to make the code more readable.

Comment: Done. Hope it's better now

Comment: Can you give more details on what the problem? For example, is it slower than without OpenMP?

Comment: What is the size of r and c?

Comment: r anc c are about 4000. The program is slower than without OpenMP, but the speedup is not satisfying.

Comment: It's not clear to me why false sharing would be a problem.  Each thread is writing to a different row and since the rows are about 4000 wide there won't be much overlap.  How are you timing your code?  What's the compiler?  Do you have optimization on (i.e. -O3 with GCC or /O2 with MSVC).

Comment: What is `tmp.m`?  Is it an array of ints?

Comment: tmp.m is the attribute of tmp and it is **bool (a matrix).
I'm timing my code with a stopwatch inside the code and I'm using -O2 optimization with g++.
Thanks for your time, by the way.

Comment: @NicolaFerro, can you tell me how the stopwatch is defined.  What function are using?

Comment: It's a header file they gave me in class. For the valutation they will use an external watch. By the way, this stopwatch uses chrono library (#include <chrono>)

Comment: @NicolaFerro, can you try `omp_get_wtime()` for the timing instead?  Why do you think false sharing is causing a problem?  Bools are usually 8-bits and a cache-line can store 64 8-bit values so if c was small (a few multiples of 64) false sharing would probably be significant but for c=4000 I don't think it is.